# Releasing unsigned apk with Fabric from different Mac

Tags: android, google-fabric, fabric-beta

it's since one year that i release unsigned apk with Fabric without problems. My work colleague has configured a new Mac for releasing sometimes the same app (always unsigned apk). If he release the apk, with Beta (Fabric) i can't install the apk.

We have the same version of Android Studio 3.4.1 and Fabric (for Android Studio) 4.3.0 .

thanks for your help.

Comment: with logcat see what error you get

Comment: Thanks for your  answer Zun. The logcat are inside Android Studio, the problem is inside Fabric Beta when is trying to install the new release.

Comment: i see these errors
https://pastebin.com/RPgtfdkn
Any help?

Comment: Could it be related to this issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24260? Have you recently updated your Android apk to 64 bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to share the same debug.keystore